# AngularJS: Ng:init - how to assign ng:model?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have ng:repeat, created by json (methods), inside it creates a series of radio buttons that are characterized by iteration (method).

Below, I need to create a variable that will be based on method selected radio button, for use in the future. I will prepare the template for clarity.

```
<li ng:repeat="method in methods">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng:model="$parent.deliveryMethod" ng:value="method" />
  </label>
</li>

<table ng:init="myValue = deliveryMethod.price | format">
  <tr>
    <td ng:bind="myValue"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I hope the point is clear. The problem is, as I understand it, ng:init is triggered earlier than time to form methods.

What I must to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're syntax looks incorrect , You should be declaring ng- as listed below :

```
ng-repeat
ng-model
ng-init
ng-bind
```

ect...

docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

upadte - to apply method to radio button try ng-change :

```
ng-change="dosomething()"
```

Comment: Hm, in one book about Angular, I read about three different three options for naming directives, is like "ng-directive", "ng:directive" or "data-ng-directive", about third I don't sure. So, maybe you're right about "ng-init", but it option of ":" is working in different case. (sorry for my English.)

Comment: @KpTheConstructor technically `:`/`_`/`-` should work, as they are taken care by directive normalization process, look at [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization)..